# AngularJS ng-pattern doesn't work with conditions as expected

Tags: angularjs

I am trying use conditions with ng-pattern but it is showing that the zip is invalid all the time. If I use the pattern without a condition everything is working fine.

```
<md-input-container flex="20">
    <label>Zip Code</label>
    <input ng-model="$ctrl.PostalCode" name="Zip" ng-required="true"
       ng-pattern="{{$ctrl.Country == 'Canada' ? '/^(\d{5}(-\d{4})?|[A-Z]\d[A-Z] *\d[A-Z]\d)$/' : '/^[0-9]*$/'}}">         
    <div ng-messages="$ctrl.testForm.Zip.$error">
        <div ng-message="pattern">Zip Code is not valid.</div>
    </div>
</md-input-container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check your pattern in rendered HTML, you can see the problem. `\` in `\d` is being ignored as you are not escaping it.
Try this:

```
ng-pattern="{{$ctrl.Country == 'Canada' ? '^(\\d{5}(-\\d{4})?|[A-Z]\\d[A-Z] *\\d[A-Z]\\d)$' : '^[0-9]*$'}}"
```